# remove specific html tag with its content by js

Tags: javascript

here is my html codes where I want to change.

```
<table>
    [some table row]
    <tr class="high">
        some text
    </tr>
    [many more table row]
</table>
```

now I want to remove the following  tag with its class and inner contents.
is there any way to remove it using replace command like "replace(/pattern/, '')".

please write a little details about how you write the patterns.

Comment: Don't use regexp to parse html.

Comment: *"now I want to remove the following tag with its class and inner contents"* Which tag? You've said "the following tag" but then haven't followed that with, you know, a tag. :-)

Comment: now I want to remove the following <tr> tag with its class and inner contents.

Comment: So you want to remove the `tr` that follows the `tr class="high"`?

Comment: @user1278128 Have you even tried anything?

Answer (score 1):

If your table have an id, say `table_id` you can do it by *pure [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)*,

```
var table = document.getElementById('table_id');
for(var i=0; i<table.rows.length;i++){
    if(table.rows[i].className=="high"){
        table.deleteRow(i);
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the jQuery library.
It offers a lot of ways to search and alter html code.

You can search for css patterns and remove the element:

```
jQuery("tr.high").remove();
```

http://www.jquery.com

Answer (score 0):

*(I'm assuming you're running JavaScript in the browser, since you're dealing with HTML.)*

Rather than trying to use regular expressions to parse HTML (which is generally a bad idea), you're probably better off actually building the DOM tree and then traversing it to get the content you need.

For instance, you can put that table in a disconnected div:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = your_html_string;
```

...and then use the DOM methods (and possibly `innerHTML`) and/or a library to get the content you need.

References:

- [DOM2 Core](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/)
- [DOM2 HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/)
- [DOM3 Core](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/)
- [`innerHTML`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/apis-in-html-documents.html#innerhtml)

---

If you're going to be doing a lot of work in JavaScript on the browser, I recommend using a good JavaScript library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries). These smooth over browser differences for you and provide a **lot** of utility functionality so you can focus on the problem at hand.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use jquery library.. its simple with that.. This should do the trick

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("tr.high").remove(); 
})
```

[Jquery .remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)